# censoring internet/social media content

Tags: internet, social-media

I'm looking for academic views on the issue of internet censorship. The censorship I'm interested on is not at the level of what China does. It's just that, given as how social networking sites such as Facebook are being used to social engineer public opinion, or to promote disinformation campaigns, just how much freedom should users have regarding their posted content? And won't any effort to filter user posts also amount to violating freedom of expression?

Comment: Welcome to Politics Stack Exchange. Please note that this is a website to exchange objective information about politics, not to debate opinions. "how much freedom should users have regarding their posted content?" and "won't any effort to filter user posts also amount to violating freedom of expression?" are both opinion-based questions, and asking for opinions of "academics" does not change that much.

Comment: You are not allowed to ask questions about censorship on social media sorry

Comment: Those are censored

Comment: Not academic, but here is a commentary from the ABA: [Social media, censorship, and coddling internet users](https://www.aei.org/technology-and-innovation/social-media-censorship-and-coddling-internet-users/). Not much [here](https://scholar.google.ca/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&as_vis=1&q=internet+censorship++social+media&btnG=) but maybe you could try other search terms. I think you could modify the Question so as not to be opinion based.